# Change packages folder path for Visual Studio NuGet Plugin

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-package-restore

I have the following directory structure in svn:

```
/src
    /.nuget
    /SolutionAandB.sln
    /A
        /trunk
            /.nuget
            /ProjectA
                /ProjectA.csproj
                /packages.config
            /packages
            /SolutionA.sln
    /B
        /trunk
            /.nuget
            /ProjectB
                /ProjectB.csproj
                /packages.config
            /packages
            /SolutionB.sln
```

This allows me to deploy A and B separately while giving me the ability to work on both A and B using one solution window (SolutionAandB.sln) instead of having to open both SolutionA.sln and SolutionB.sln.

In the src/.nuget/NuGet.targets files, my restore command is the following:

```
<RestoreCommand>
$(NuGetCommand) install "$(PackagesConfig)" -source "$(PackageSources)" $(NonInteractiveSwitch) $(RequireConsentSwitch) -solutionDir $(PaddedSolutionDir) -OutputDirectory "$(MSBuildProjectDirectory)\..\packages"
</RestoreCommand>
```

When building SolutionAandB.sln, the OutputDirectory parameter makes sure the packages for A and B are installed in the respective trunk folder. But when I use the NuGet Plugin, it shows that no packages are installed (even though they are installed correctly inside trunk/packages) and says:

> "Some NuGet packages are missing from this solution. Click to restore
>   from your online package sources."

If I click restore on that message, it installs all packages to src/packages which is not the desired behavior.

This is an issue when trying to add new packages (reference hint paths are messed up) or update existing using the plugin (installed packages tab shows an empty list).

Is there a way I can tell the plugin to look at the respective trunk/packages folder instead of src/packages folder from SolutionAandB.sln?

Answer (score 0):

I think, you overworking yourself. Here what you should do

```
/src
    /.nuget
    /packages
    /SolutionForAllProjects.sln
    /Project A
        /.nuget
        /ProjectA.csproj    
    /Project B
        /.nuget
        /ProjectB.csproj
```

And in your projects nuget.config add

```
<config>
    <add key="repositoryPath" value="..\packages" />
</config>
```

You may need to re-add references or manually fix them

Comment: I considered using this structure instead but this doesn't work quite well with branches. We create an RC branch before releases (branches/RC) from trunk, which would require reference hint paths along with the repository path to updated every time the branch is created.

Comment: @SiddharthShukramani in my description everything under `src` is one product, and all projects belong to it. You release all or nothing.

Comment: We want the ability to release ProjectA and ProjectB separately. The solution for all projects is mostly for productivity purposes.

Comment: @SiddharthShukramani, well, again, if whatever is in sub folder is your releasable product, it should be treated as a unit. If project "A" and "B" have common components, those can be build in "common" solution and treated similarly to third-party. What I see often, most people who have these problem, trying to "fix it", while in reality, project/solution/release structure has to be engineered upfront.